# adjunct or complement

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adjectives, infinitives, complements

My question is whether these sentences are each grammatical or not:

> **a)** As a common language, English is good to communicate with you.
> **b)** As a common language, English is good to communicate with you in.

In my view, **a)** and **b)** are both grammatical.

Specifically, "to communicate with you" in the sentence **a)** is an *infinitive of specification* working as an adverbial phrase that is just an adjunct, whereas the sentence **b)** is a so-called *tough construction* and "to communicate with you in" is the complement of the adjective "good" that works here as a so-called *two-place* (or *transitive*) adjective.

Am I right or wrong?

EDIT:

Thanks for the quick answer.

> Infinitival relatives aside, infinitivals are always complements, not modifiers, since they must be licensed by the head.

If so, is **c)** wrong where **d)** is correct in the following examples?

> **c)**  “Less carbs” is better (than “few carbs”) to discuss the amount of whole carbs.
> **d)**  “Less carbs” is better (than “few carbs”) to discuss the amount of whole carbs with.

Example **c)**, which I think has the same syntax as **a)**, was actually a sentence I posted on the site linked below and that’s why I had a second thought that **a)** was correct as well, though I had a first intuition that **a)** was lacking the terminal preposition.

https://youtu.be/NfmsGlCGTEE?si=IBt8WJHLmbv0iG5v

Comment: Why you used "in"??

Comment: @Sam I would actually choose the version **with** "in" over the one without it. Compare OP's sentences with this one: *"It is good to communicate with you **in** English as a common language."* It just doesn't work without the preposition. I don't see why the preposition should go away when the sentence gets rearranged. Although, I **do** agree that ending the sentence with "in" sounds kind of awkward. Also: I wouldn't use the infinitive in either a) or b) -- it doesn't seem *incorrect*, but it does seem *unusual.*

Comment: @Sam The more common way of expressing that idea would be *"As a common language, English is good **for** communicating with you."* Oddly enough, this version seems fine without the preposition "in."

Comment: **in** there is an echo of "speak in".  *They are speaking **in** English.*  So: "What language shall we communicate in?"

Comment: English is a good language for me to communicate with you in. English is a common language we can communicate in. Yours read slightly awkwardly.

Comment: Let OP add a comment. I’m sorry b) is a poor sentence as English, but my focus is on its grammaticality. I picked up an original sentence from a short youtube clip and altered it to post this question. In the clip, a Japanese guy is talking online with a suspicious person who is out of sight. The invisible person, speaking in poor Japanese with an Asian-type accent, insists that he is an American. So, the Japanese challenged him to speak English saying “I think English is better to communicate with you.”

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between **good for** and **good to**.

**good for** can express the idea of *suitability* and **good to** can express the idea of *advisability*. Those abstract ideas can sometimes be very close to each other and difficult to tell apart, especially since it is always advisable to do what is suitable. Your example is blending the two ideas in a slightly unidiomatic manner.

The adjective **good** when it means "suitable" is accompanied by **for**, which takes a nominal complement:

> A shovel is good for digging.
>
> A walk after dinner is good for the digestion.
>
> Strong rope is good for climbing.

The adjective **good** when it means "advisable (for someone)" is followed by **to**, which takes a verbal complement.

> It is good <sup>(for you)</sup> to look before you leap.
>
> Strong rope is good <sup>(for climbers)</sup> to bring on a climbing expedition.

English is *suitable* for communication as it is a common language:

> As a common language, English is good for communicating in.<sup>superbly colloquial</sup>
>
> As a common language, English is good for communication.

It is *advisable* to use English for communication when the speakers speak different native languages:

> It is good to communicate in English as a common language.
>
> It is good for us to communicate in English as a common language.

and the somewhat awkward, not ungrammatical yet not quite idiomatic, blended version where suitability and advisability are being blended into a salad dressing, since those for whom it is advisable to use English are present semantically but invisible:

> English is good <sup>(for us, for someone)</sup> to communicate in.
>
> English is good to communicate with.

Your second set of examples about "carbs"...

If **less carbs** is the subject of your sentence, you would speak of the suitability of the phrase using "better for":

> Is “less carbs”  **better for** the total amount of carbs in something?

And if you are asking whether it's advisable to use the phrase:

> Is it **better to say** "less carbs" to refer to the total amount of carbs in something?

Answer (score 0):

> a) *As a common language, English is good* [*to communicate with you*].
>
> b) *As a common language, English is good to communicate with you in.*

b), with its terminal preposition "in", is correct.

The syntax you mentioned is not quite right: in **both** examples the bracketed expression is not an adverbial phrase functioning as an adjunct, but an infinitival clause functioning as complement of "good". Infinitival relatives aside, infinitivals are always complements, not modifiers, since they must be licensed by the head.

In b) the object of "in" is missing but understood as "English".